# help html5 and css3

Tags: html, css

I need help to understand responsive web design. Every time I scroll down or up mu mney width start to chagned. I have everything in % form but I does not help at all.

```
#Main-Wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}


.Main-Header {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.Main-Header nav {
    background-color: #DDD;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 60%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 42px; /* 42 px*/
}
```

This is the code I use

```
<div id="Main-Wrapper">
    <header class="Main-Header">
        <img src="css/Images/Logo.jpg">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in here that is supposed to be responsive or change with scrolling. Can you elaborate and perhaps create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the width on .Main-Header. Or if that does not work, Add this: `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: okey thanks for quick replay I will try it out and see if it work

Answer (score 0):

Yes it work on the layout. But the  still changed